# How to use python black formatter under a project for python>=3.5 managed by poetry?

Tags: python, python-poetry

I created a python project "foo" with Poetry.
This is the content of `pyproject.toml`:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "bar"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = ">=3.5"

[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry>=0.12"]
build-backend = "poetry.masonry.api"
```

This package is compatible with Python3.5.
I want to [black](https://github.com/psf/black) formatter, which is not compatible with Python3.5.
I think there is no problem if I use Python>=3.6 for development, but I cannot install black formatter:

```sh
$ poetry add black --dev
[SolverProblemError]
The current project's Python requirement (>=3.5) is not compatible with some of the required packages Python requirement:
  - black requires Python >=3.6

Because no versions of black match >19.10b0,<20.0
 and black (19.10b0) requires Python >=3.6, black is forbidden.
So, because bar depends on black (^19.10b0), version solving failed.
```

So I installed black directly with `pip`:

```sh
$ poetry run pip install black
```

This way doesn't sit well with me. I want to install `black` by poetry.

How should I do? (I don't want to modify the dependency to `python>=3.6`)

Comment: If you don't want to change the python version constraint, you have no chance to install `black` with `poetry` within your venv. You could add black to your global python installation instead (if there the python version matches).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems a bit late but actually you can do what you want even if black supports only Python >=3.6.2

In your pyproject.toml you can define a restricted dependcy as documented in https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/#python-restricted-dependencies

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = ">=3.5"

[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]
black = {version = "^21.7b0", python = ">=3.6.2"}
```

Poetry won't complain and you won't have any problems since it is a dev dependency.

Answer (score 3):

You need to edit the python value in your `pyproject.toml`:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "bar"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = ">=3.6"

[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry>=0.12"]
build-backend = "poetry.masonry.api"
```

Comment: I want to use this library with python3.5, though I can use python>=3.6 for development

Comment: You cannot because the minimum required version of python for black is 3.6. See https://github.com/psf/black/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Yes, I know it. But I can use black in development environment, which uses Python>=3.6. So what I want to know is the way to change the python version for dev dependency.

Comment: I think it is not possible, as much as i know.

Comment: I up voted your answer, but I've already known the way and it is not what I want to know. If there are no answers in a little more time, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: maybe you can install python3.6 and run black using python3.6 to format your code

Comment: I would recommend to not set the python version constraint to `>=3.6`, because than you say that your project will be compatible to all version >=3.6. When adding a new dependency, poetry checks if this dependency matches your python version constraint (and not the currently used python version). I guess it will than fail quite often, because lots of packages have an upper boundary for python. Use `^3.6` instead, which means `>=3.6,<4.0` or `>=3.6,<3.9` to say you support all official releases from 3.6 on.